# PermissionError: [Errno 13] при копирование файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

Копируются файла из одной директории в другую. Файлы отбираются по временному штампу. Вылетает ошибка - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Запускаю из консоли с правами администратора.

```
from shutil import copyfile
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


backup_dir = open(r'C:\to_copy', 'wb')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\from copy'):
    for file in files:
        for_backup = os.path.join(root, file)
        file_modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(for_backup))
        if datetime.now() - file_modified < timedelta(minutes=5):
            copyfile(for_backup, backup_dir)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
copyfile(for_backup, backup_dir)
```

`copyfile` - копируем файл, второй параметр должен быть именем файла. Но у вас  `backup_dir` - папка, а не файл.
Упс!

Чтобы копировать файлы в указанную папку используйте `shutil.copy(source_file, target_dir)`.

Comment: Спасибо @Эникейщик, это то, что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

В строке

```
backup_dir = open(r'C:\to_copy', 'wb')
```

Вы пытаетесь открыть директорию на запись (как файл), из-за чего возникает ошибка. Можно просто написать

```
backup_dir = r'C:\to_copy'
```

Далее вы передаёте функции

```
copyfile(for_backup, backup_dir)
```

в качестве второго аргумента директорию `backup_dir`, в то время как это должно быть имя копии файла. Для того, чтобы копировать файлы в директорию можно использовать (как указано в соседнем ответе)

```
shutil.copy(source_file, target_dir)
```

либо можно добавлять к названию директории, куда вы хотите копировать, имя файла и затем передавать его в функцию `copyfile`:

```
file_backup = os.path.join(backup_dir, file)
copyfile(for_backup, file_backup)
```